# Add one or two more PHP variables to the javascript code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am a decent PHP programer and recently I got stuck in a javascript code.

I have the code below:

```js
$(function () {

    $('.more').live("click", function () {
        var ID = $(this).attr("id");

        if (ID) {
            $("#more" + ID).html('<img src="moreajax.gif" />');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "scripts/loadmore.php",
                data: "lastmsg=" + ID,
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) {
                    $("div#updates").append(html);
                    $("#more" + ID).remove();
                }
            });
        } else {
            $(".morebox").html('The End');

        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

This code submit without problems one PHP variable to the process page loadmore.php using this input

```html
<div id="more<?= $load_id ?>" class="morebox" style="margin-bottom: 200px;">
    <a href="#" class="more" id="<?php echo $load_id; ?>">
        load more
    </a>
</div>
```

How can put more variables in the input and the javascript code to work with them on the process page?

I want to set one or two more variables.

UPDATE:

I updated the code like this:

HTML input:

```html
<div id="more<?= $load_id ?>" class="morebox" style="margin-bottom: 200px;">
<a href="#" class="more" data-id="<?php echo $load_id; ?>" data-act="<?php echo $act; ?>">load more</a></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

$('.more').live("click",function() 
{
var ID     = $(this).attr("data-id");
var ACT = $(this).attr("data-act");

if(ID)
{
$("#more"+ID).html('<img src="moreajax.gif" />');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "scripts/loadmore.php",
data: {"lastmsg="+ ID, "act="+ ACT},
cache: false,
success: function(html){
$("div#updates").append(html);
$("#more"+ID).remove();
}
});
}
else{
$(".morebox").html('The End');
}

return false;

});
});

</script>
```

I am not sure if the data lines was writed properly because the script looks like it's frozen now

SOLVED:

I just used a datastring like this

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

$('.more').live("click",function() 
{
var ID     = $(this).attr("data-id");
var ACT = $(this).attr("data-act");
var dataString = 'lastmsg='+ ID + '&act=' + ACT;

if(ID)
{
$("#more"+ID).html('<img src="moreajax.gif" />');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "scripts/loadmore.php",
data: dataString,
//data: {"lastmsg="+ ID, "act="+ ACT },
cache: false,
success: function(html){
$("div#updates").append(html);
$("#more"+ID).remove();
}
});
}
else{
$(".morebox").html('The End');
}

return false;

});
});

</script>
```

Comment: Put the second PHP variable the same way as the first one. Where is problem?

Comment: use the `data` attribute instead, ie `data-id="1" data-something="yes"` and use `$(this).data('id')` and `$(this).data('something')` to use them

Comment: I followed your sugestions and i modified the script like this:
<a href="#" class="more" data-id="<?php echo $load_id; ?>" data-act="<?php echo $act; ?>">load more</a></div>



var ID     = $(this).attr("data-id");
var ACT = $(this).attr("data-act");

data: {"lastmsg="+ ID, "act="+ ACT, },

I am not sure if the data lines was writed properly because the script looks like is frozen now

Comment: If you solved it you should put your solution in an answer and not edit into the question. You can then accept your own answer to note that your problem now has a solution. You get points for doing this. It is how Stack Overflow works. See the [tour]

Answer (score 2):

Just send data as an object:

```
data: {
  "lastmsg": "lastmsg="+ ID,
  "anotherData": "someData"
}
```

You'll retrieve them in your PHP script as follows:

```
$_POST["lastmsg"];
$_POST["anotherData"];
```

Comment: Just a little correction - it is an object, otherwise +1.

Comment: There are no associative arrays in JavaScript, it is an object.

Comment: @cezar made a little research here and you are right. Edited accordingly.

Comment: I understand you what you mean, but there is no such a thing explicitly called "associative array" in JavaScript. They are called associative arrays in PHP, but in JavaScript there are objects, and arrays are also a special kind of objects. The answer is besides this dispute about the terminology correct.